# Multiple Scenario User Input Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, discord, discord.py

Upon a given prompt (Message1), the user should be able to respond either left, right, or stay still and the discord bot will provide a custom message (either one of Message2-4). I've tried to create multiple checks to detect for different user responses to no avail. I looked online for other solutions, some of which mentioned using asyncio, but I am not too familiar with it and even after using it, failed to solve the problem. Any help is appreciated, I am fairly new to python. Thank you.

Code below:

```
if message.content.startswith('gametest'):
        channel = message.channel
        await channel.send('Would you like to play?')

        def check(m):
            return m.content == 'yes' and m.channel == channel

        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
        await channel.send('Message1')

        def check2(m):
            return m.content == 'left' and m.channel == channel
        def check3(m):
            return m.content == 'right' and m.channel == channel
        def check4(m):
            return m.content == 'stay still' and m.channel == channel

        msg2 = await client.wait_for('message', timeout=30.0, check=check2)
        await channel.send('Message2')

        msg3 = await client.wait_for('message', timeout=30.0, check=check3)
        await channel.send('Message3')

        msg4 = await client.wait_for('message', timeout=30.0, check=check4)
        await channel.send('Message4')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare if the message content is in a list

```py
>>> content = 'right'
>>> valid_responses = ['right', 'left', 'stay still']
>>> content in valid_responses
True
```

You can use the same principle in the check function

```py
def check(m):
    return m.content in ['right', 'left', 'stay still'] and m.channel == channel
```

If you want it to be case-insensitive you can use the `str.lower()` method

```py
def check(m):
    return m.content.lower() in ['right', 'left', 'stay still'] and m.channel == channel
```